# Fixing DPI from .xinitrc

Tags: x11, i3

**Problem:** I recently installed `nvidia-beta` drivers on my Arch Linux build (switching from `nouveau`). It made all of the fonts extremely small on my i3 window manager.

**The Temporary Fix:** Running `startx -- -dpi 100` fixes the problem.

**Question:** Is there a way to force the `-dpi 100` flag into my `~/.xinitrc` so that I can just run `startx` as usual?

**EDIT:** Font is still extremely small in GViM. Perhaps my `-dpi 100` fix didn't work as well as I thought it would.

Comment: It's probably better to set `DisplaySize` in the `Monitor` section.

Answer (score 1):

As Katsura-san suggested, there may be a better way to configure your X server for your graphics card and monitor.

See also the manual pages *startx(1)* and *xinit(1)*.

The basic answer to your question is to create a script `$HOME/.xserverrc` which starts the desired server binary with the desired arguments.

Also, see the *xset(1)* manual page, and in particular the various `fp` sub-commands.  You may want to re-order the fonts to put TTF fonts and the the better resolution fonts before the poor resolution fonts.  `xset q` will show you your current font path.

Answer (score 0):

The default **DPI** (**D**ots **P**er **I**nch) is 96. When set to `100` font size increased by 4% which might not be noticeable. To confirm initial DPI use one of these commands:

```bash
$ xdpyinfo | grep dots
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch

$ grep DPI /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[     9.555] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (43, 44); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[     9.761] (==) modeset(G0): DPI set to (96, 96)
```

For myself when I encounter a program that doesn't do DPI scaling very well, I use a value of `144` which is a 50% increase and then call the program:

```bash
xrandr --dpi 144
/path/to/program-not-hdpi-aware
```